# SQL QUERY - people with common values

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a database of an hospital.
so.. i got a table with 2 columns: patients_ID ,treatment_ID and for the record lets say we have another third primary key column , doesn't matter what exactly.
now, I want to extract from the table all the patients_ID who got at least (or more) all the treatment's that patient with id of '1' have.

for example:

```
patients_ID           treatment_ID

    1                     111
    1                     222
    1                     333
    2                     111
    2                     333
    5                     111
    5                     222
    5                     333
    5                     444
```

as you can see, from the table above I would want my query to return the table:

```
patients_ID
     5
```

cause only he's got the same treatment as patient id=1 , and i don't care that he also got treatment 444 in addition to that.

patient_id=2 doesn't belong cause he's missing treatment "222".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
   patients.id
FROM
(
    SELECT treatment_id FROM yourTable WHERE patients_id = 1
)
    filter
CROSS JOIN
    patients   -- A table with all patients
LEFT JOIN
    yourTable
        ON  yourTable.treatment_id = filter.treatment_id
        AND yourTable.patients_id  = patients.id
WHERE
    patients.id <> 1
GROUP BY
    patients.id
HAVING
    COUNT(filter.treatment_id) = COUNT(yourTable.treatment_id)
```

*(If you don't have a patients table, you really should have one and should create one.  But you can use `(SELECT patients_id FROM yourTable GROUP BY patients_id)` as a last resort.)*

Or....

```
SELECT
   yourTable.patients_id
FROM
(
    SELECT treatment_id FROM yourTable WHERE patients_id = 1
)
    filter
INNER JOIN
    yourTable
        ON  yourTable.treatment_id = filter.treatment_id
WHERE
    yourTable.patients_id <> 1
GROUP BY
   yourTable.patients_id
HAVING
    COUNT(yourTable.treatment_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable WHERE patients_id = 1)
```

Comment: was just about to comment on the same..if you edit,i won't post mine.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala post yours, might be better / different / more educated than mine...

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala You need to undelete it ;)

Comment: @MatBailie the first query would not give the result you expect. It would return patients_id 2 and 5. The second query would return patients_id  5 which is the expected result. But in the case patients_id 2 had treatment 333 twice then the result would be patients_id 2 and 5. There's no guarantee that either of the two querys will return the expected result _("...all the patients_ID who got at least (or more) all the treatment's that patient with id of '1' have.")_

Comment: @EmilioCeroleni That was true before I made my edit 18 minutes before your comment *(when I commented that it doesn't work)*.  But the edit that included two answers, both appear to work correctly.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c5157/4

Answer (score 0):

Get all treatments for patient 1, cross join this with all other patients other than 1 and left join the original table and check for the same treatment counts.

```
select p.patient_id
from (select treatment_id from tbl where patient_id=1) t
cross join (select distinct patient_id from tbl where patient_id<>1) p
left join tbl on tbl.patient_id=p.patient_id and t.treatment_id=tbl.treatment_id
group by p.patient_id
having count(t.treatment_id) = count(tbl.treatment_id)
```

Comment: Errr, you need to move the `t1.patient_id=1` to a `WHERE` clause.  Having it as a predicated on a `LEFT JOIN` means that `t1` isn't being filtered, resulting in the whole table being joined against itself.

Answer (score 0):

With this script you can test not only those patients that, at least once, had every treatment patient 1 did but any other patient as well. For example, by setting `@patient_id = 2` you should get 1 and 5 and so on. I also tried it playing around with the records and worked fine.

```
--MSSQL variable declaration
declare @patient_id int;
--MySQL variable declaration and value assignment
--MSSQL value assignment
set @patient_id = 1;

select patients_id as cnt from patients as t 
inner join
    (select distinct treatment_id from patients where patients_id = 
@patient_id) as tr on tr.treatment_id = t.treatment_id 
group by patients_id 
having count(distinct t.treatment_id)  = (select count(distinct 
treatment_id) from patients where patients_id = @patient_id) 
and patients_id <> @patient_id
```